# Downloading a public file from Google Cloud to Google colaboratory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I have a dataset which is publicly hosted on google cloud at [this link](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/ravens-matrices). I would like to use this data in a Google colaboratory notebook by downloading it there. However all the tutorials I have seen which involve transferring a file from the Cloud to Colab require a Project ID, which I don't have since this is not my project. Wget also doesn't work with this file. Is there a way to download the files at that link directly to a colab notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful, your files are very big. It can easily fill up all Colab space.

First you need to login (authenticate yourself).

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

Then, you can use `gsutil` to list the files.

```
!gsutil ls gs://ravens-matrices/analogies/
```

And to copy 1 or more files, to the current directory.

```
!gsutil cp gs://ravens-matrices/analogies/extrapolation.tar.gz .
```

Here's a [working notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1h1RCp0aghZQzSnLQv3RTqgEZnwYvQM8A?usp=sharing)